# Windows Server 2008 R2 alias or Cname

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

On one of our client server, Windows Server 2008 R2 is installed. On the same machine, on SQL Server 2012, I am seeing 2 server names MHMSDB01 and user_DB1 are actually same server (IP address.) host name is MHMSDB01.

But I have access to MHMSDB01 through Windows authentication but do not have on the other. It gives error that

Login from untrusted domain.
I want to know how this setup is done. I checked alias option in SQL Server Configuration Manager but I could not see any alias there. I checked cliconfig.exe but could not find any alias name there as well.

I ran nslookup command for MHMSDB01 and user_db1 and both returned same IP address and DNS name as MHMSDB01.xyz.com. I am new to this area. I want to know the relation between them and how they have been setup. Please ask me further questions know if I have not given sufficient information.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but it sounds like you have two SQL Server named instances on the server. Either that or you are browsing for database instances and finding another instance on the network. Can you post a screenshot of where you're seeing these two names?

Comment: They are the same server only - MHMSDB01. But I can not login when I use user_db1 as server name and use windows authentication. They both are same instance 'MSSQLSERVER'.Both have same data and log files. @@Servername returns same result for both and that is ;;'MHMSDB01'.  I 'm sorry but My organisation has blocked screenshot functionality so I can not post it here.